# Customize redirect login page when authenticating with Google - ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, google-authentication

I am working with ASP.NET Core 5 and my web app need to authenticate and authorize user based on their role with email, password login as well as Google login.

It has been working well but what I need is that if the user is not authorized, my login page is shown to the user.

In details, my code for authentication in `Startup.cs`:

[image: Code in my Startup.cs]

And code in my `HomeController.cs`:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

When I press the button to /Home, the web just redirect me to the **Google's login page**. I want that it will redirect to /Login with the code in my `LoginController.cs`:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

On my Login page, there will be a button to go to Google's login page.
And, most important, I don't use the Identity framework for this!
Hope you can help me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the solution for this problem. Just need to get rid of the line of code:

```
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

Then it will show my own Login page!
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn");
```

Or

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options => 
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
        });
```

keep in mind your path is correct or not.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for helping but it still redirect me to the Google Login page, not my Login view. It is really weird though